# How to build dependency (ex highlight.js) with bower?

Tags: javascript, node.js, assets, bower

I added `highlight.js` to `bower.json` and installed it.

But there are only sources of `highlight.js`, how can I compile it using bower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bower is just download the dependencies. Installation is depends on what development environment are you at? Single page application with Yeoman? Node.JS web application with Express? Or something else.

There are some JS task runners like `grunt` or `gulp`. I prefer `grunt`. If you are using `grunt`, there is exist `grunt`'s task runner for it called [`grunt-bower-task`](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task) that will `install` your downloaded bower components into specific folder that meets our need.

I recommend you to use/ learn [`Yeoman`](http://yeoman.io/) that is included `yo` the scaffolding, `bower` the dependencies manager, and `grunt` the task runner if you are starting `single page application` development.

So basically `bower` is just `front end dependency manager` unlike NPM which is `NodeJS dependency/ package manager` that we usually use at backend/ web server.

Comment: Thanks. I have NodeJS in this project (I'm using elixir (gulp wrapper)), but how can I write a task for it to run a single command? I've never used it before.

Comment: Since I have no experience with `gulp` so I don't quite unterstand about it. Maybe you can look at some of this source:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower
http://ericlbarnes.com/setting-gulp-bower-bootstrap-sass-fontawesome/
http://bower.io/docs/tools/
http://truongtx.me/2014/07/18/using-bower-with-gulp/

Sorry if not helping :D

Answer (score -1):

since you are using `bower` to install `highlight.js`, i believe it's used at client side.

you don't need to compile javascript at all, you just need to load it and use it globally.

there are several ways to load it into global execution context:

- inline script in html `<script src="path/to/bower/component/highlight.js"></script>`
- using front-end AMD modularization tool like `requirejs`
- use front-end CMD modularization tool like `browserify`, `webpack`